# Submit a method in webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, methods, browser, submit, invokemember

I have a problem invoking a submit method in web page

This is my code

```
Webbrowser.document.forms(0).invokemember("submit")
```

It does nothing.

Here is the html

```
<form name="myWebForm" action="myServerSideScript.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 1<br /> 
    <input type="text" /> Text Field 1<br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set .AllowNavigation property to "TRUE"

```
Webbrowser.AllowNavigation = True
```

And call submit method like this

```
Webbrowser.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

Or

```
Webbrowser.Document.Forms.GetElementsByName("myWebForm").Item(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```