# How to send value in php textbox from vb.net

Tags: php, html, vb.net

I want to send variable value from my vb.net to php 
my html code looks like this

```html
<form action="something.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="mat-input" id="first-name">
</form>
```

Now when I press enter this form will submit and I have to make vb.net for this

I already try

```php
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("first-name").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
 Private Sub submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
 WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://example.net/something/something.php")
 End Sub
```

Comment: You don't want to navigate to `something.php`, you want to submit the form.

Comment: okay please can you give me some solution

Comment: Please add more information. E.g., what is the result... errors, `null` or `undefined`, etc. Completing and understanding the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) will increase you're response-rate from this community and the likelihood of resolution.

Comment: Just google "vb.net webbrowser submit form". There is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15456224/6664878) for that on stackoverflow. A little search and you would have solved your problem in less time than it took to compose this question

Comment: Added language formatting